# Input.GetAxis("Vertical") returns -1 by default in Unity 4.2

Tags: input, keyboard, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I had a code in Unity UnityScript, it was working in the morning, and I did not change anything.

Now I opened Unity again, it asked "*do you want to update Unity*?" ,  I say yes, now it is downloading UnitySetup-4.3.1.exe in Chrome. This may be relevant to the issue.

Anyway, now I ran my code, and noticed something unusual.

changed my code to this :

```
function Update()
{
   Debug.Log(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
}
```

it prints `-1`, although I'm not pressing anything, or none of my keys are stuck.

I tried restarting Unity. Changing my code back and forth, so it "rebuilds" (hopefully) the application. None of them worked. Maybe there is some other way to refresh the project ?

Has anyone faced an issue like this? Any ideas for a solution?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: I also realized that the "down" axis is stuck when I'm playing an online Unity game in Kongregate. I will try installing the latest version of Unity. Will it affect Unity Web Player? We will see :)

Answer (score 3):

I know this is super old question but the same issue faced me with Unity 5.3.3f1, just navigate to Edit -> Project Settings -> Inputs

You'll find 4 (Array Element) for both "Vertical" & "Horizontal" 2 each, delete the duplicate ones and you're good to go.

Answer (score -1):

This is expected. As per the [documentation here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html):

> The value will be in the range -1...1 for keyboard and joystick input.
>   If the axis is setup to be delta mouse movement, the mouse delta is
>   multiplied by the axis sensitivity and the range is not -1...1.

Comment: You are correct about the range. But when I don't press anything, the value should be 0. Am I wrong ?

Comment: Take a look at what 'Vertical' has been mapped to. Maybe it has been unmapped and therefore returns -1.

Answer (score -1):

Installing the latest version (4.3.1) and restarting Unity solved the issue..